# How do I convert the below string as date-time in R?

Tags: r, posixct, as.date

I have the following character vector that contains date/time. I want to convert them to a date format and I tried the below methods : `as.Date()` and `as.POSIXct()`

```
time <- c("Oct 01,2015 15:38:31 ", "Oct 05,2015 11:07:14", "Oct 11,2015 14:15:51 ", "Oct 11,2015 14:19:53 ", "Oct 12,2015 11:23:28", "Oct 19,2015 16:32:51 ")

    #as.Date() is skipping the time part
time_1<-as.Date(time,"%b %d,%Y %H:%M:%S")
time_1
  [1] "2015-10-01" "2015-10-05" "2015-10-11" "2015-10-11" "2015-10-12" "2015-10-19"


#POSIXct is showing an error
time_2<-as.POSIXlt(time,"%b %d,%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

The `as.Date()` function is skipping the time part and `POSIX` is throwing an error (which is obvious).

How do I convert the above string as a proper date+time format?

Comment: Simply add `format =` to `as.POSIXlt`. Please read the help page.

Comment: You can use `strptime(time, format = "%b %d,%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the `format` in both `as.POSIXlt` and `as.POSIXct`

```
 as.POSIXlt(time,format="%b %d,%Y %H:%M:%S")
 #[1] "2015-10-01 15:38:31 IST" "2015-10-05 11:07:14 IST"
 #[3] "2015-10-11 14:15:51 IST" "2015-10-11 14:19:53 IST"
 #[5] "2015-10-12 11:23:28 IST" "2015-10-19 16:32:51 IST"
```

Without specifying the `format`, the function guesses the `"%b %d,%Y %H:%M:%S"` as the timezone (`tz`). The second argument is `tz` as per the default formula in the `?as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(x, tz = "", ...)
```